# SQL many-to-many relationship with Join and Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a many-to-many SQL query, and then join the results with other tables.

I have 5 tables: articles, hashtags, articles_hashtags (which maps hashtags.id and articles.id), users, authors.

If I want to query all articles and get author and user info together, I use this query, and it works:

```
SELECT articles.*, authors.name as authorName, users.name as userName
    FROM articles
    LEFT JOIN authors ON articles.authorId = authors.id
    LEFT JOIN users ON articles.userId = users.id
```

Otherwise if I try to query all articles with a certain hashtag, I use this (as found out [here](http://tagging.pui.ch/post/37027745720/tags-database-schemas)):

```
SELECT articles.*
    FROM articles, hashtags, articles_hashtags
    WHERE hashtags.id = articles_hashtags.hashtagId
    AND (hashtags.name IN ('prova'))
    AND articles.id = articles_hashtags.articleId
    GROUP BY articles.id
```

But on this second one how can I join the informations from the other tables (users and authors)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are looking for this

I assume that you are looking for all matching records

```
    SELECT art.*
    FROM articles art
    INNER JOIN articles_hashtags arc_hs ON art.id = arc_hs.articleId
    INNER JOIN hashtags hs on hs.id = arc_hs.hashtagId
    INNER JOIN authors aut ON art.authorId = aut.id
    INNER JOIN users u ON art.userId = u.id
    WHERE hs.name IN ('prova')
    GROUP BY art.id
```

If you want all information of articals  regardless of having matching records  in other tables then you can  use `left join`

```
  SELECT art.*
    FROM articles art
    LEFT JOIN articles_hashtags arc_hs ON art.id = arc_hs.articleId
    LEFT JOIN hashtags hs on hs.id = arc_hs.hashtagId
    LEFT JOIN authors aut ON art.authorId = aut.id
    LEFT JOIN users u ON art.userId = u.id
    WHERE hs.name IN ('prova')
    GROUP BY art.id
```

**Note:** You are using `CARTESIAN JOIN` in your second query which is `very bad`

Comment: Thanks! It works—with a few corrections (I guess because you couldn't try the query). 
Here is the correct one
`SELECT art.*
    FROM articles art
    INNER JOIN articles_hashtags arc_hs ON art.id = arc_hs.articleId
    INNER JOIN hashtags hs ON hs.id = arc_hs.hashtagId
    INNER JOIN authors aut ON art.authorId = aut.id
    INNER JOIN users u ON art.userId = u.id
    WHERE hs.name IN ('prova')
    GROUP BY art.id`. If you correct this in your answer i'll mark the question as "solved"!

Comment: @addis Yes i did not try .

Comment: There's not actually a Cartesian join in the second query of the question. The joins are in the `WHERE` clause, which should be discouraged, but all of the tables are joined.

Comment: @addis And make sure, you have indices on id, articleId, hashtagId, authorId and name fields